# Altering Google Forms Questions

Tags: google-forms

Is it possible to alter the "Short answer text" in a "Short answer" questions in google forms? The "Short answer text" can be found under "Untitled Question" when a new question is added to a Google Form.

[image: screenshot of google form]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look possible that I can see.  I also checked the script API guide to build custom forms, I didn't see it there either.

Your best bet is to add a description under the title to guide what you are looking for.